# How to add a waiting div over another?

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="shouldBeOverlapped">
content
</div>
```

now I want to add another div on it (e.g. waiting) so it will 100% cover it and make it unclickable, preferably transparented. How to do it?

Comment: Try to search for "overlay"

Comment: Add a div(waiting) with `position:absolute` `background:transparent` `left:0px` `top:0px` and set its dimension to `div.shouldBeOverlapped`

Answer (score 1):

Try to search for "overlay". This will be the right thing.

Example here:

```css
#overlay {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.5;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="shouldBeOverlapped">
content
</div>
<div id="overlay"></div>
```

Comment: This implementation would place an overlay over the element containing `div.shouldBeOverlapped` rather than just the div itself.

Comment: @anierzad Isn't this what he want?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to put that waiting div as a `:before`. Although it is limited, it can be easy to set up.

```css
#textToHide {
  background: yellow;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
}

#textToHide:before {
  content: '';
  position:absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="textToHide">
This text is protected against selection... although we could still look for it in the source code...
</div>
```

Comment: hmm, this looks pretty elegant, but why is it "limited" ?

Comment: You can only put "text" content in it, no HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You need a containing `div` element with it's position attribute set to `relative`. This defines the bounds of the overlay. Without it the overlay will look up the DOM until it finds a parent it can get it's positioning information from. If it doesn't find one, it will cover the entire page body.

I've created a JSFiddle for you here: https://jsfiddle.net/aogd164t/

Try removing `position: relative` from the `container` class and see the result.